# Word Document in QAxWidget doesn't have scrollbars

Tags: c++, qt, ms-word, activex

I'm displaying a word document in QAxWidget.

```
QAxWidget *axWidget = new QAxWidget;
axWidget->setControl(changelogTempFile->fileName());
axWidget->setFixedSize(400,300);
axWidget->show();
```

However eventough the whole document does not fit in the viewport I have no scrollbars.

I even tried to use Frameset object to explicitly add scrollbars but it was in vain.

```
QAxObject *frame = ui->axW_singleChl_doc->querySubObject("Frameset");
if( frame )
  frame->setProperty("FrameScrollbarType","wdScrollBarTypeYes");
```

I  received following error message:

```
QAxBase: Error calling IDispatch member Frameset: Exception thrown by server
             Code       : 6027
             Source     : Microsoft Word
             Description: Die Eigenschaft Document.Frameset ist nur verf?gbar, wenn Document.Type WdFrameset entspricht
             Help       : wdmain11.chm [25507]
         Connect to the exception(int,QString,QString,QString) signal to catch this exception
```

Description translated means, that property Document.Frameset is only available if Document.type is WdFrameSet

How can this be achieved? Many thanks in advance,

James

Comment: Just info about why Frameset didn't work: Frameset is only available if the Word document is a "web page" and frames have been defined for that web page. Then the frame in/on the Word HTML document can have scrollbars. It's not the same "frameset" as the control you're trying to use (about which I know nothing).

Comment: @CindyMeister: Thanks for clarification.